# Can't understand Facebook login in server side

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api

I try to understand how to use Facebook login API on the server side,
What do I suppose to save in the DB if any?
What do I need to check in my DB?
Do my server need to check anything whit FB server?
Do this diagram is correct?
User->FB login->User(with FB token?)->My server->My DB?->FB server?
[image: Facebook login diagram]

Answer (score 1):

> What do I suppose to save in the DB if any?

Nothing, if you don´t want to.

> What do I need to check in my DB?

You can detect returning authorized users by storing their ID.

> Do my server need to check anything whit FB server?

You can do API calls client side or server side. For example, with the JS SDK or the PHP SDK, or some C# SDK if there is one. So your server does not "need" to do with FB, but it can.

> Do this diagram is correct? User->FB login->User(with FB token?)->My server->My DB?->FB server?

Yes, it is correct if you do client login (and/or API calls) and server side API calls as well.

I would suggest just playing around with the JS SDK a lot first.

Comment: Thanks you very much for your answers, but I still don't understand how it can be only client side call, so I will be a little more specific, I have API and mobile app, in the mobile app I don't have any problems, What do I need to do on the server(API) side? if I understand  it correctly I need to call FB from the server with the data(FB ID and token) that the user get and check if it correct and only then let the user login, am I right?

Comment: you really don´t need any server side api calls in general. you only need that to identify returning users. you can transfer the token to the server and do the calls with that token.